# BigQuery: select the nth smallest value in window, ordered by another value

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

My table has two integer columns: `a` and `b`. For each row, I want to select the nth smallest value of `b` among the rows with smaller `a` values. Here's a sample input/output, with n=2.

Input:

```
 a | b 
-------
 1 | 4 
 2 | 2 
 3 | 5 
 4 | 3 
 5 | 9 
 6 | 1 
 7 | 7 
 8 | 6 
 9 | 0
```

Output:

```
 a | 2th min b
 -------------
 1 | null  ← only 1 element in [4], no 2nd min
 2 | 4     ← 2nd min between [4,2]
 3 | 4     ← 2nd min between [4,2,5]
 4 | 3     ← 2nd min between [4,2,5,3]
 5 | 3     ← etc.
 6 | 2
 7 | 2
 8 | 2
 9 | 1
```

I used n=2 here to keep it simple, but in practice, I want the 2000th smallest value (or some other large-ish constant). The column `a` can be assumed to contain distinct integers (and even 1, 2, 3, … if that's easier).

The problem is that if I use `ORDER BY b` in my window clause and `NTH_VALUE`, it just computes the answer on the wrong set of values:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT 1 AS a, 4 AS b
  UNION ALL SELECT 2 AS a, 2 AS b
  UNION ALL SELECT 3 AS a, 5 AS b
  UNION ALL SELECT 4 AS a, 3 AS b
  UNION ALL SELECT 5 AS a, 9 AS b
  UNION ALL SELECT 6 AS a, 1 AS b
)
SELECT nth_value(b, 2) over (order by a)
from data
```

returns `[null, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]`: the values are ordered by `a` (so in the same order than they appear), so the value `b=2` is always the one in second place. I want to order by a and *then* take the nth smallest value of b. Any idea how to write this in BigQuery (preferably Standard SQL)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and produces correct result for given example.

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 a, 4 b UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 0 
)
SELECT 
a, 
(SELECT b FROM 
  (SELECT b FROM UNNEST(c) b ORDER BY b LIMIT 2)
  ORDER BY b DESC LIMIT 1
) b2
FROM (
  SELECT a, IF(ARRAY_LENGTH(c) > 1, c, [NULL]) c 
  FROM (
    SELECT a, ARRAY_AGG(b) OVER (ORDER BY a) c
    FROM `project.dataset.table`
  )
)
-- ORDER BY a
```

with expected result as below

```
Row a   b2   
1   1   null     
2   2   4    
3   3   4    
4   4   3    
5   5   3    
6   6   2    
7   7   2    
8   8   2    
9   9   1
```

Note: to make it work for 2000th element you might change 2 to 2000 in `LIMIT 2`

meantime, i can admit it looks a little ugly/messy to me and not sure about scalability but you can give it a shot

> Quick Update

Below is a little less ugly looking version (same output of course)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 a, 4 b UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 0 
)
SELECT a, c[SAFE_ORDINAL(2)] b2 FROM (
  SELECT x.a, ARRAY_AGG(y.b ORDER BY y.b LIMIT 2) c
  FROM `project.dataset.table` x
  CROSS JOIN `project.dataset.table` y
  WHERE y.a <= x.a
  GROUP BY x.a
)
-- ORDER BY a
```

For 2000th element replace `2` to `2000` in `LIMIT 2` and `SAFE_ORDINAL(2)` 
Still potentially same issue with scalability because of (now) explicit CROSS JOIN

Comment: . . I was about to write something similar, but I was going to use `row_number()` after the `unnest()`.

Comment: That works, although it unfortunately doesn't scale well enough for my data =( I'll try to do some sampling and maybe add more conditions on the WHERE based on the distribution of b to avoid the quadratic explosion.

Comment: thank yo for confirming. i suspected issue with scaling :o( with data as is. so sampling might be a way